# Python Basemap fails

Tags: python-2.7, basemap, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Anaconda 2.1.0 and Basemap installation is successful

```
conda install basemap
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I try to project lat,lon to a planar:

```
Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 286.
```

My code looks like this:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
from pymongo import MongoClient
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

p = Basemap(projection='sinu',lon_0=0,resolution='c') #fails here

projected_xy = p([24.4,45.1])
```

The code fails even before attempting to project.

Comment: Which version of geos are you using? The assertion error line says : "unsupported childBoundable type". The path to that assertion from your code isn't obvious, but either one of the parameters is wrong or there is a bug somewhere in the stack.

Comment: Also, do you definitely have proj4 installed?

Comment: I have geos version 3.3.3 and proj4 4.8.0-0 for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Basemap has to be imported before shapely.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import shapely.geometry as sg
```

Doing the import the other way around will cause the error.